# Ubuntu 12.10 not suspending

Tags: 12.10, suspend

i'm having a problem with my Asus s400 with ubuntu 12.10 installed. It's set to suspend when closing the lid, but it doesn't. It doesn't suspend from the menu either, it blinks and the screen comes back 2 seconds later.

I tried the second script provided here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290&page=6

and it works, but ust the first time. After the lid is closed and the laptop gets suspended it comes back normally, but won't suspend again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled the same. On `Gnome`, I can successfully suspend by running from terminal:

```
$ sudo pm-suspend
```

[cf](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume)